# Update Project Version, or other Project Settings, from command line

Tags: unreal-4

#### Is it possible to update UE4 Project Settings from command line?

More specifically I would love to be able to update the following Project Settings attributes from command line using, for instance, `RunUAT.bat`

- Project > Description > `Project Version`
- Platform > Android > `Store Version`
- Platform > Android > `Version Display Name`
- Platform > IOS > `Version Info`

I have checked the unreal documentation without finding anything, and looked through the [documentation for ue4 cli](https://adamrehn.com/docs/ue4cli/overview/introduction-to-ue4cli), also without any luck.

I have already tried to read the `Config/DefaultEditor.ini` file (and other INI files) using various tools, but apparently the INI format used by UE4 is somehow different than what the parsers I have tested accepts. (`+`-icons for indicating array elements and so on)

Am I missing something obvious? Or is this not normal to do?

---

Running from Windows, MacOS, or Linux (whichever will work)

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own script to update the files. Here is a python example to update lines in the DefaultGame.ini

```
import fileinput
import sys

defaultGameFilePath = 'Config/DefaultGame.ini'
stagingDirectory = 'path/you/want'

for line in fileinput.input(defaultGameFilePath, inplace=True):

    key = line.strip().split("=", 1)[0]

    if key == "StagingDirectory":
        print(key + "=(Path=\"" + stagingDirectory + "\")")
    else:
        print('{}'.format(line), end='')
```

This will not modify arrays +/-, you will have to extend the script for that. I also had trouble using third party ini packages. Unreal ini files do seem to have their own unconventional format.